# How to change/remove the left border line from Pycharm?

Tags: user-interface, styles, pycharm

Is there a way to remove/change color of the line on the left?

Note: this is *not* the tear line.

[image]

Info: Ubuntu 14.04, pycharm version 2016.1.4

Answer (score 1):

Go to: `Settings` > `Editor` > `Color & Fonts` > `General` > `Editor` > `Tear Line`

[image]

Them make it be the same color of your backgound....

Comment: thanks, but on my picture this is not the tear line -- see what I get after your proposed change: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/no-tear-line.png    (after your answer i updated the question to distinguish from the tear line)